# connect conditional statement to form javascript

Tags: javascript

I've just started learning javascript.  I'm trying to create a condition that will turn some text red or blue depending on a number entered into a form, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.  Every time the text turns blue no matter what number is entered.  It should turn red if the number entered is less than 50.  This is what I have:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

var input = document.getElementById("input");

var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.onclick = function() {
  if (input >= 50) {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = "blue";
  };
}
```

```html
<h3 id="color">Conditional Example</h3>
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" id="input"><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: An HTML element can never be more than a number.

Comment: It shoiuld be `parseInt(input.value, 10)` to get the value entered into the input and convert it to a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the value of the input element.

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
submit.onclick = function(event) {
  // getting the value after click of the button
  var input = document.getElementById("input").value;

  if (input >= 50) {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = "blue";
  };
}
```

```html
<h3 id="color">Conditional Example</h3>
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" id="input"><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("input")` gets the actual element. You want the **value** of that element, so use `document.getElementById("input").value`. You also want to check the value on every click, so you need to move that line within your click handler:

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

var submit = document.getElementById("submit");

submit.onclick = function() {
  var input = parseInt( document.getElementById("input").value, 10 );
  if (input >= 50) {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = "red";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("color").style.color = "blue";
  };
}
```

```html
<h3 id="color">Conditional Example</h3>
<form name="form">
  <input type="text" id="input"><br>
  <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't really need to move the DOM selection to the handler. Just the `.value` access. Not that it really matters. Just pointing it out.

Comment: @squint yes, true